# Dialogflow followup intent not triggering on Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

**The setup:**

My 'Default Welcome Intent' asks the user "Choose between Amsterdam, Berlin, Frankfurt, London".

Then I've created a **custom** followup intent.
I've also created an entity called 'location', which I've added the four cities to.

My followup intent looks like this:

[image: followup intent screenshot]

**Here's the problem:**

When I run the app in Actions on Google simulator, it always triggers the "Default Fallback Intent", and doesn't trigger the followup intent.

[image]

**Here are some more screenshots of my setup, as requested in the comments:**
[image: entity screenshot]
[image: intent list screenshot]
[image: Followup intent 1/2]
[image: Followup intent 2/2]

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the location Entity, the Welcome intent, and a full screen shot of the Followup Intent? You may also want to include a screen shot of the Intent list, showing the initial and followup intents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was me not reading the documentation properly. I've stupidly skipped the part where it explains how to accept card responses.

```
app.intent('Carousel - OPTION', (conv, params, option) => {
  const SELECTED_ITEM_RESPONSES = {
    'SELECTION_KEY_ONE': 'You selected the first item',
    'SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_HOME': 'You selected the Google Home!',
    'SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_PIXEL': 'You selected the Google Pixel!',
  };
  conv.ask(SELECTED_ITEM_RESPONSES[option]);
  conv.ask('Which response would you like to see next?');
});
```

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses